# Fedora 19: can't disable the firewall

Tags: fedora, firewall, services

I've installed a server (WSO2 ESB) in my laptop.

When I run it, going to the browser and typing the console address `https://10.13.6.75:9443/carbon`, it works normally, but if I try it on another machine on the network, it gives timeout.

Some observations:

- ping works
- telnet respond on ssh port (22) but not in 23, 8080, 9443, etc
- I've already executed `service firewalld stop`, `service iptables stop`, and disabled the `selinux`, but no results.

There's another process involved blocking the requests?

Comment: It 's paerfectly normal that ssh can't connect on 23 8080 or anything but 22 with default config

Comment: @Kiwy OP wants to check if port is open, not to initiate SSH connection.

Comment: Can you tell us what web admin interface are you using there is chance you need to extends the listenning address of it.

Comment: @Kiwy Is a common web interface. There's another addresses like wsdl url, rest services url, but none of these works outside my laptop, just on localhost.

Comment: There's no folder `/etc/apache`

Comment: @Kiwy - he's on Fedora, that's a Debian/Ubuntu file. Please only attempt to assist if you know specifics. Otherwise you're just confusing the OP and the Q&A.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fedora 19 uses the firewall `firewalld.service`. You can see if it's running from a terminal using this command:

```
$ systemctl status firewalld.service 
firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2014-01-11 17:02:00 EST; 4 days ago
 Main PID: 564 (firewalld)
   CGroup: name=systemd:/system/firewalld.service
           └─564 /usr/bin/python /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid

Jan 11 17:02:00 greeneggs.bubba.net systemd[1]: Started firewalld - dynamic firewall d...n.
```

You can disable it, temporarily like this:

```
$ sudo systemctl stop firewalld.service
```

Now it's off.

```
$ systemctl status firewalld.service 
firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2014-01-16 10:20:42 EST; 11s ago
 Main PID: 564 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: name=systemd:/system/firewalld.service

Jan 11 17:02:00 greeneggs.bubba.net systemd[1]: Started firewalld - dynamic firewall d...n.
Jan 16 10:20:39 greeneggs.bubba.net systemd[1]: Stopping firewalld - dynamic firewall .....
Jan 16 10:20:42 greeneggs.bubba.net systemd[1]: Stopped firewalld - dynamic firewall d...n.
```

To restart it:

```
$ sudo systemctl start firewalld.service
```

If you're new to Fedora, or just new to 19, I highly suggest reading the Fedora Project's documentation on firewalld.

- https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD

#### What ports are open?

You can use the command line tool `nmap` to see what ports are accepting connections on your system.

```
$ sudo nmap -sS -P0  192.168.1.161/32

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-01-16 11:06 EST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.161
Host is up (0.000019s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
111/tcp open  rpcbind

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.11 seconds
```

Be sure to substitute your system's IP address in the above command.

#### netstat

Alternatively you can use the command `netstat` to see what ports are in use and which PIDs and IP's they're bound on.

```
$ sudo netstat -anpt | grep :22
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      894/sshd            
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.161:52732     67.253.170.83:22        ESTABLISHED 5023/ssh            
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      894/sshd
```

**NOTE:** This lists the IP addresses that have `sshd` bound to port 22.

#### Binding to ports on specific interfaces

Many people get confused by this but each interface in IPv4 has it's own set of ports. You need ot make sure that when you start a service that you take care to tell the app that you want it to bind to IP address's 127.0.0.1's port XYZ vs. the IP address for you NIC card's port XYZ.

You application appears to provide this type of feature. It's discussed in this documentation.

- http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB460/Setting+Up+Host+Names+and+Ports

There's an XML file according to the docs where you can change your IP to bind to.

```
<parameter name="bind-address" locked="false">hostname or IP address</parameter>
```

Comment: The status is `Active: inactive (dead)`

Comment: use nmap to see if ports are open, not ssh

Comment: @ThorstenStaerk - thanks added suggestion showing how.

Comment: @Elias - if it's in the state of dead, you shoule try restarting it. `sudo systemctl restart firewalld.service`.

Comment: Really, using nmap, the ports opened is 22, 111, 9999, 10000 and 11111.

Comment: Why the bind was not on specified ip?

Comment: @Elias - how do you mean? If you mean it shows up using 0.0.0.0 that means all IP addresses. Each IP has ports associated to it. So you can bind on 127.0.0.1's port 22 and also on your IP's port 22, or on all interfaces (network cards) port 22.

Comment: Executing `nmap -sS -P0 10.13.6.75/32` that is the address visible for other machines on network, it show only those five ports opened.

Comment: The ports 9443, 8280, 8243 (used by the WSO2 server) should be listed.

Comment: @Elias - I'm not familiar with your app, can you post a link to it? There is either a command line switch or a config file where you have to specify what interface it should bind on. Your issue likely isn't with the firewall. Try the same command on 127.0.0.1 to see if it's bound to that port.

Comment: is there a difference what happens if you do telnet server 9443 vs telnet server 9445?

Comment: @Elias - go through this doc for WSO2 ESB, it shows how to configure your app to bind on other interfaces. http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB460/Setting+Up+Host+Names+and+Ports

Comment: It's the WSO2 ESB 4.6.0 (http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus). The awkward is that nmap with 127.0.0.1 show the same ports, but if I try to access the url via browser on port 9443, it works.

Comment: You can also use the command `netstat -aptn` to see what services are listening on which ports.

Comment: @Elias - I'm stepping out so I won't be replying.

Comment: With nestat, the port of the console (9443) appears like `tcp6       0      0 :::9443                 :::*                    LISTEN      8025/java`. I guess it's wrong

Comment: That's binding to the IPv6 address, not the IPv4. That's why it wasn't showing up.